# iText PDF PArser does not parse the data as a whole word with octet-stream

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, text-extraction

I'm trying to parse a pdf file using itextsharp (version: 5.5.1.0). The pdf file has content-type as "application/octet-stream". I'm using C# code to read based on Location Strategy

```
base.RenderText(renderInfo);

//Get the bounding box for the chunk of text
var bottomLeft = renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
var topRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();

//Create a rectangle from it
var rect = new Rectangle(
    bottomLeft[Vector.I1],
    bottomLeft[Vector.I2],
    topRight[Vector.I1],
    topRight[Vector.I2]);
var word = renderInfo.GetText().Trim();

// get column no
var position = (int)rect.Left;
```

Pdf file image

[image: Pdf file image]

Issue: When I read it RenderInfo.GetText() I get incomplete words like instead of "Daily" I get "Dai" and "ly" in next loop. Is there any way I canread complete word by word ?

Please let me know if you need more info, unfortunately there is no option to attach the pdf file here.

Regards
Pradeep Jain

Answer (score 0):

> When I read it RenderInfo.GetText() I get incomplete words like instead of "Daily" I get "Dai" and "ly" in next loop.

That behavior is expected.

In a render listener / text extraction strategy you get the individual atomic string parameters of text drawing instructions. There is no requirement for PDF creation software to put whole words into these strings.

Actually the PDF format even encourages this splitting of words! It does not by itself use the kerning information of fonts; thus, any software that wants to create text output with kerning has to split strings wherever kerning comes into play and sligthly move the text insertion point between the string parts in text drawing instructions.

Thus, a render listener has to collect the strings and glue them together before it can expect to get whole words.

> Is there any way I canread complete word by word ?

Yes, by collecting the strings and gluing them together.

You mentioned you *read based on Location Strategy* - then look closer at what the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` itself does: In its `RenderText` implementation it collects the text pieces with some coordinates, and only after collecting all those pieces, it sorts them and glues them together in its `GetResultantText` method. (You can find the code [here](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/LocationTextExtractionStrategy.cs).)

Unfortunately many members of that strategy are not immediately available in derived classes, so you may have to resort to reflection or simply to copying the whole class code and change it in situ.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had to go for different option of first converting it to csv and then reading csv file. I will look into your option to see if I get whole words word.